# Unable to Pass Variables to Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to pass two dates to my php script via an Ajax call but it fails and returns no data. When I include only one variable everything works fine and data is returned. I do not think my problem is in my PHP script but I included into below just in case. Is my syntax for reading in two variables correct?

Here is my ajax javascript call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(coxDrawChartDate);

function coxDrawChartDate(startDate,endDate) {

  jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {start: startDate , end: endDate},
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/automationBarDataCoxDate.php',
      success: function(jsonData) {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
          var options = {
              legend: {
                  position: 'left'
              },
              bars: 'vertical',
              width: '1000',
              height: '500',
          };

          var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('cox_barchart'));
          chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
  });


}
```

And here is my php script:

```
    <?php
// Database credentials
$dbHost = '10.21.124.252';
$dbUsername = 'demouser';
$dbPassword = 'Welcome1';
$dbName = 'syndicationdashboard';
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$startDate = intval($_POST['start']);
$endDate =intval($_POST['value']);

// Create connection and select db
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

// Get data from database
$sql = "SELECT Priority, Automated, isAutomatable, isNotAutomatable FROM automation_progress WHERE platform = 'Cox' AND update_date >= '".$startDate."' AND update_date <= '".$endDate."' AND update_date IN (SELECT MAX(update_date) FROM automation_progress WHERE platform = 'Cox' AND update_date >= '".$startDate."' AND update_date <= '".$endDate."') ORDER BY priority";

if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if (count($data) === 0) {
            $data[] = array_keys($row);
        }

       $data[] = [
           $row['Priority'],
           intval($row['Automated']),
           intval($row['isAutomatable']),
            intval($row['isNotAutomatable']),
       ];
   }

   mysqli_close($db);

   echo json_encode($data);

}
?>
```

Comment: Your function `coxDrawChartDate` requires two parameters

Comment: I am passing two parameters to the function. When I debug the code the function is providing the right info but the ajax call fails

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$startDate = intval($_POST['start']);
$endDate =intval($_POST['value']);
```

`$_POST['value']`

doesn't exist, should be

`$_POST['end']`

Comment: I have made this change and this not getting any data back. Thanks for catching that mistake

Comment: If you're still not getting results, check how dates are formatted and if their format is compatible with what MySQL expects.

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript you wrote

```
 data: {start: startDate , end: endDate}
```

so you'll be sending two POST variables called "start" and "end". You can verify this by watching the AJAX call in your browser's developer tools (in the Network tab) and seeing what is sent in the AJAX request's body.

But your PHP is looking for a POST variable called "value", which you didn't send. This will likely cause your database query to fail with a syntax error, or execute but match no rows, since `$endDate` won't be populated.

Changing `$_POST["value"]` to `$_POST["end"]` will let you capture the value in PHP.

You can verify what POST values are received by the server by adding `var_dump($_POST);` as a temporary debugging line near the start of your PHP script. This will output the whole contents of POST to your response, so you can see what variables exist in it and what their names are.

You might also want to consider logging errors and/or returning an error message in your response if `mysqli_query()` returns false (indicating failure), so that you can more easily identify the root of problems and speed up your debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue. I was formatting the $_POST to and intval. Once I removed this from the PHP file everything worked fine. So I updated these two lines from:

```
$startDate = intval($_POST['start']);
$endDate =intval($_POST['end']);
```

to:

```
$startDate = $_POST['start'];
$endDate = $_POST['end'];
```

Comment: `$endDate =intval($_POST['end']);` didn't even exist in the code sample you posted.... it was using "value" as per the other two answers to the question. But yes, good spot that you shouldn't be using intval to parse a date. I hadn't noticed that but it certainly won't help.